# Context Value Defined in Component, but Returns Undefined in a Function Within the Same Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, tiptap

## Context Variable Issue

Hello everyone!  I'm currently facing an issue with the `userID` context variable.

**Problem Description:**

The `userID` is initially set within the `UserContextProvider` component in `UserContext.jsx`. However, when I print the `userID` value right above the `handleJournalCreateAndUpdate` function in `Editor.jsx`, it displays the expected value. Strangely, within the `handleJournalCreateAndUpdate` function, the `userID` is coming up as `undefined`.

**Observation:**

I've noticed that making any changes to the `jsx` file containing the `Editor` component causes the `userID` value to suddenly become available within the `handleJournalCreateAndUpdate` function. This behavior raises questions about the timing or order of execution.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or assistance in understanding why the `userID` variable behaves this way within the mentioned context. Thank you!

### Current Setup:

#### UserContext.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { getUserProfile } from '../services/authService';

// Create the context with an initial value of null
const UserContext = createContext();

// Create a provider component to wrap your app with
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    const isCurrentPathAuthPage = ['/register', '/login'].includes(
        location.pathname
    );

    const fetchUserProfileAndUpdate = async () => {
        if (!user) {
            const token = Cookies.get('AuthToken');
            if (!token) {
                if (!isCurrentPathAuthPage) {
                    navigate('/login');
                }

                return;
            }

            try {
                const response = await getUserProfile(token);
                setUser(response.user);
                setUserID(response.user._id);
            } catch (error) {
                if (!isCurrentPathAuthPage) {
                    navigate('/login');
                }
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!user) {
            fetchUserProfileAndUpdate();
        }
    }, [user, location.pathname]);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, userID }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

// Create a custom hook to easily access the context value
export const useUser = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(UserContext);

    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useUser must be used within a UserContextProvider');
    }

    return context;
};
```

#### Main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';
import './styles/preflight.css';
import './styles/index.css';
import { ThemeProvider } from './contexts/ThemeContext';
import { MenuProvider } from './contexts/NavDrawerContext.jsx';
import { FocusModeProvider } from './contexts/FocusModeContext.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/UserContext.jsx';

ThemeProvider;
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <UserContextProvider>
                    <MenuProvider>
                        <FocusModeProvider>
                            <App />
                        </FocusModeProvider>
                    </MenuProvider>
                </UserContextProvider>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

#### Editor.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    BlockNoteView,
    useBlockNote,
    getDefaultReactSlashMenuItems,
} from '@blocknote/react';
import '@blocknote/core/style.css';
import EditorMenu from './EditorMenu';
import Layout from '../../containers/Layout';

import PromptDisplayCard from './PromptDisplayCard';
import { useTheme } from '../../contexts/ThemeContext';
import { useUser } from '../../contexts/UserContext';
import {
    createJournalEntry,
    getJournalEntryById,
    updateJournalEntry,
} from '../../services/journalEntryService';

//  Variable to keep track of whether a journal entry has been created to prevent multiple entries due to async nature of the JS
let isJournalEntryCreated =
    localStorage.getItem('isJournalEntryCreated') === 'true';

// Main TextEditor component
const Editor = () => {
    const { userID } = useUser();
    const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
    const [selectedBlocks, setSelectedBlocks] = useState([]);
    const [isSelectionActive, setIsSelectionActive] = useState(false);
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
    const [isPromptDisplayVisible, setIsPromptDisplayVisible] = useState(false);
    const [currentMood, setCurrentMood] = useState('happy');
    const [isFocusModeOn, setIsFocusModeOn] = useState(false);
    const [journalID, setJournalID] = useState(() =>
        localStorage.getItem('journalID')
    );
    const [isTextEditorMenuCollapsed, setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed] =
        useState(false);
    const containerRef = useRef(null);
    // Function to scroll to the bottom of the editor
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight;
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (journalID) {
            getJournalEntryById(journalID).then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    // setContent(response.content);
                    // setCurrentMood(response.mood);
                }
            });
        }
    }, []);

    console.log(userID); // has value
    async function handleJournalCreateAndUpdate(editor) {
        console.log('userID', userID?.length); // Undefined


        // Update the content state and scroll to the bottom of the editor
        const newContent = editor.topLevelBlocks;
        captureSelectedBlocks(editor);
        setContent(newContent);
        scrollToBottom();

        if (
            !isJournalEntryCreated &&
            newContent?.length &&
            userID?.length &&
            !journalID
        ) {
            try {
                if (!userID.length) {
                    console.error('User ID not available');
                    return;
                }
                isJournalEntryCreated = true;
                localStorage.setItem('isJournalEntryCreated', true);
                const response = await createJournalEntry(
                    userID,
                    newContent,
                    'happy'
                );
                console.log('response', response._id);
                setJournalID(response._id);
                localStorage.setItem('journalID', journalID);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Failed to create journal entry:', error);
                isJournalEntryCreated = false;
                localStorage.setItem('isJournalEntryCreated', false);
            }
        } else if (
            isJournalEntryCreated &&
            newContent?.length &&
            journalID?.length
        ) {
            try {
                if (!journalID.length) {
                    console.error('Journal ID not available');
                    return;
                }
                await updateJournalEntry(journalID, 'content', newContent);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Failed to update journal entry:', error);
            }
        }
    }

    const { blockNoteTheme, toggleDarkMode } = useTheme();

    // Customize the slash menu items
    const customizeMenuItems = () => {
        const removeHintsAndShortcuts = (item) => {
            const newItem = { ...item };
            delete newItem.hint;
            delete newItem.shortcut;
            if (newItem.group === 'Basic blocks') {
                newItem.group = 'Basic';
            }
            return newItem;
        };

        const defaultMenuItems = [...getDefaultReactSlashMenuItems()];
        const customizedMenuItems = defaultMenuItems.map(
            removeHintsAndShortcuts
        );
        return customizedMenuItems;
    };

    //  Initialize the editor instance
    const editor = useBlockNote({
        initialContent: content,
        slashMenuItems: customizeMenuItems(),
        onEditorReady: () => {
            editor.focus('end');
            scrollToBottom();
        },

        onEditorContentChange: handleJournalCreateAndUpdate,

        onTextCursorPositionChange: (editor) => {
            captureSelectedBlocks(editor);
        },
    });

    // Function to capture selected blocks
    const captureSelectedBlocks = useCallback(
        (editor) => {
            const currentSelectedBlocks = editor.getSelection()?.blocks;
            const currentActiveBlock = editor.getTextCursorPosition().block;

            if (currentSelectedBlocks) {
                setSelectedBlocks(currentSelectedBlocks);
                setIsSelectionActive(true);
            } else {
                isSelectionActive && setIsSelectionActive(false);
                setSelectedBlocks([currentActiveBlock]);
            }
        },
        [selectedBlocks, isSelectionActive]
    );

    // Renders the editor instance using a React component.
    return (
        <Layout
            currentMood={currentMood}
            setCurrentMood={setCurrentMood}
            isFocusModeOn={isFocusModeOn}
            setIsFocusModeOn={setIsFocusModeOn}
            setIsPromptDisplayVisible={setIsPromptDisplayVisible}
            setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed={setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
            toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
            showFocusModeAndMoodDropdown={true}
        >
            //Rest of the code
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Editor;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of research in [the source code of the BlockNote](https://github.com/TypeCellOS/BlockNote/blob/main/packages/react/src/hooks/useBlockNote.ts), I found out that the problem is that you are missing updating the reference of the `handleJournalCreateAndUpdate` function. the solution might help you understand better:

You must pass a `dependencies list` (just like the 2nd argument of `useEffect`) to the `useBlockNote` to re-run its inner-useEffect, which will update the reference of the `handleJournalCreateAndUpdate` function. So, you can access the latest value of the `userID` in your function.

```
const editor = useBlockNote({
    ...
}, [userID]);
```

however, a better solution and practice is to use `useCallback` which will make your code cleaner and more optimized in the future:

```
import {useCallback} from "react"

...

const handleJournalCreateAndUpdate = useCallback(() => {
    ...
}, [userID, /* and other dependencies or states */])

const editor = useBlockNote({
    ...,
    onEditorContentChange: handleJournalCreateAndUpdate,
    ...
}, [handleJournalCreateAndUpdate]);
```